# multiple file download using rest client in java

Tags: java, rest, client

I want to save multiple files from my rest client. Below code will save only one file but I want it for multiple files.

```
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("MyContacts.xls");

int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your InputStream in a [PushbackInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html).
You can read N bytes from the stream and then unread() them to reuse the stream.

Comment: Here is my server side code.public MultipartBody fetchExtractedImage() throws Exception {
  List<Attachment> attachments = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
  File file1 = new File("D:\\attachments\\infiles\\db.jpg");
  File file2 = new File("D:\\attachments\\infiles\\test.pdf");
  if(file1.isFile() && file2.isFile()) { 
   attachments.add(new Attachment(file1.getName(), "application/octet-stream", file1));
   attachments.add(new Attachment(file2.getName(), "application/pdf", file2));
  return new MultipartBody(attachments, true); 
}